# IndexError: list index out of range with Google Vision

Tags: python, opencv, google-vision

I'm trying to take a region of a picture using OpenCV, and then extracting that text. It seems that I can only take 2 horizontal texts at most. If I try three or a vertical text it gives me the IndexError. I tried changing texts[0] to texts but that gives me "AttributeError: 'RepeatedComposite' object has no attribute 'description'".

```
img_path = "10.png"
img_raw = cv2.imread(img_path)

ROIs = cv2.selectROIs("Select Rois", img_raw, 0)
print(ROIs)

crop_number = 0


for rect in ROIs:
    x1 = rect[0]
    y1 = rect[1]
    x2 = rect[2]
    y2 = rect[3]


    img_crop = img_raw[y1:y1 + y2, x1:x1 + x2]\
    cv2.imshow("crop" + str(crop_number), img_crop)

    success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', img_crop)
    roi_image = encoded_image.tobytes()
    roi_image = vision_v1.Image(content=roi_image)
    response = client.text_detection(image=roi_image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print(texts[0].description)
    crop_number += 1
```

Comment: I think anyone who knows enough about the Windows API to answer this may not be familiar enough with MacOS to know what "a Mac's spotlight-like search engine" is or does.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is far _too broad_ to be on-topic.